# Elastic kibana selection of points (geopoints) in complex polygon

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble with what seems like a fairly basic use case, but I'm hitting certain limitations in Kibana and problems with certain geo data types. It's starting to feel like I'm just approaching it wrong.

I have a relatively large point data set (locations) of type geo_point, with a map and dashboard built. I now want to add a complex AOI. I took the shapefile, dissolved it so it became one feature instead of many, converted it to geojson and uploaded it (to create an index) via the Kibana Maps functionality. I then made it available as layer, and wanted to just allow it to be selected, show tooltip, and then Filter by Feature. Unfortunately I then received an error saying along the lines that this would be too large an operation to be posted to the URL - which I understand as there are over 2 million characters in the geojson.

Instead I thought I could write the query somehow according to the guidance on: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html
with the pre-indexed shape.

However, it doesn't seem to work to allow geo_point to be queried against geo_shape.
e.g.

```
    GET /locations_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_point": {
      "geolocation": {
        "relation": "within",
        "indexed_shape": { 
          "index": "aoi_index",
          "id":    "GYruUnMBfgunZ6kjA8qn",
          "path":  "coordinates"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives an error of:

```
    {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "no [query] registered for [geo_point]",
        "line" : 3,
        "col" : 18
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "no [query] registered for [geo_point]",
    "line" : 3,
    "col" : 18
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Do I need to convert my points index to be geoshape instead of geopoints? Or is there a simpler way?
I note the documentation at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-by-geopoint.html suggests that I can query by geo_polygon, but I can't see any way of referencing my pre-indexed shape, instead of having the huge chunk of JSON in the query (as the example suggests).

Can anyone point me (even roughly) in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704434/8160318) you can utilize `indexed_shape`. Let me know if this answer is sufficient to get you started.

Comment: That's a helpful guide to help me get started, provided I convert locations stored as geoshape instead of geopoints. Thanks.